# How can I upload a .parquet file from my local machine to Azure Storage Data Lake Gen2?

Tags: python, azure, parquet, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a set of .parquet files in my local machine that I am trying to upload to a container in Data Lake Gen2.

I cannot do the following:

```
def upload_file_to_directory():
    try:

        file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="my-file-system")

        directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("my-directory")
        
        file_client = directory_client.create_file("uploaded-file.parquet")
        local_file = open("C:\\file-to-upload.parquet",'r')

        file_contents = local_file.read()

        file_client.append_data(data=file_contents, offset=0, length=len(file_contents))

        file_client.flush_data(len(file_contents))

    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
```

because the .parquet file cannot read by the .read() function.

When I try do this:

```
def upload_file_to_directory():

     file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="my-file-system")

     directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("my-directory")
        
     file_client = directory_client.create_file("uploaded-file.parquet")
     file_client.upload_file("C:\\file-to-upload.txt",'r')
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataLakeFileClient' object has no attribute 'upload_file'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving this because you have imported `DataLakeFileClient` module. Try installing `DataLakeServiceClient` since it has `upload_file` method.

```
pip install DataLakeServiceClient
```

However, to read the .parquet file, one of the workarounds is to use `pandas`. Below is the code that worked for me.

```
storage_account_name='<ACCOUNT_NAME>'
storage_account_key='ACCOUNT_KEY'

service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
            "https", storage_account_name), credential=storage_account_key)
    
file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="container")

directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client(directory="directory")
        
file_client = directory_client.create_file("uploaded-file.parquet")

local_file = pd.read_parquet("<YOUR_FILE_NAME>.parquet")
df = pd.DataFrame(local_file).to_parquet()

file_client.upload_data(data=df,overwrite=True) #Either of the lines works
#file_client.append_data(data=df, offset=0, length=len(df)) 
file_client.flush_data(len(df))
```

and you may be required to import `DataLakeFileClient` library to make this work:

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
import pandas as pd
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Comment: This is a good answer. I'll only note that the Python API may have changed since June. DataLakeServiceClient has an upload() method but for .NET, not for Python, and DataLakeFileClient now has an upload_data() method.